# Tracking clicks on email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, data-views

Is there a way to track the clicks in the email while on journey? and send the tracked links to specific email?

Comment: Hi Jon - did we manage to answer your question? :) Anything more i / we can do to help? if not, please select the best answer so it's marked as solved

Answer (score 2):

The conceptual design for a real-time scenario that you depict, will require the following:

- One cloud page
- Ampscript on each of the links
- Data Extension to store click(s) (if you need them to reference)
- Emails and Triggered Send Definitions
- Technical skills

The framework would be as follows. 
Each link in the email would direct to a landing page and pass a parameter indicating what link is clicked. e.g.

```
www.landingpage.com?LinkParamter=A
```

Now, when you hit the landing page you'll need to catch this parameter and do everything you need from there. It would look something like this;

```
%%[ VAR @LinkParameter, @SubscriberKey, @ActualLink
SET @SubscriberKey = _subscriberKey
SET @LinkParamter = QueryParameter("LinkParameter")

IF @LinkParameter = "A" THEN
   SET @ActualLink = "www.google.com"
   /* Do your data updates here - could be this */
   UpsertData("DataExtension",1,"SubscriberKey",@SubscriberKey,"LinkClicked",@ActualLink)

   /* Then after updating necessary data, trigger an email */
    Modify the code for triggered sends found here: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/create_a_triggered_send_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_web_service_api/

   /* Then after triggering the notifcation to the clickee, you trigger the email to the one you need to notify */
   Repeat triggered send ampscript here, but with different email and maybe different subscriberkey if you'd like

   /* Then finally redirect them to end destination */
   Redirect(@ActualLink)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Then you repeat this per link you want to do this with in the email. E.g. Link Parameter B, C, D etc.

In order to succeed with your quest, you need someone who's comfortable with the above process.

Hope this helps you get where you need to be :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use an [Engagement Split Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/use_the_engagement_split_activity/) to track if a Contact clicks on a link within an email, then you will be able to route them down a 'yes' branch and they receive can a subsequent email.

Comment: how will I collect and send those who clicked to a certain email?

Comment: This is exactly what the Engagement Split Activity does. Have you tried it?

Comment: Oh I meant convert the clicks into Data Extension and send that DE to a certain email address. Just to collect and track the data of those who click specific link.

Comment: The Engagement Split Activity can track specific links. You would need to add an Update Contact Data Activity to the yes branch to update a DE and add an Email Activity.

Comment: Like this one?
http://oi68.tinypic.com/11t6cls.jpg

What will be the DE inside update contact?

Comment: no need to set up Data View on this?

Comment: Yes, your screenshot looks correct. You don't need to use data views to achieve this.

Comment: You shouldn't need an Update Contact Data Activity unless you have a specific need to store data in a DE.

Comment: I think it is much better to store the clicks in a DE. Could you please help me on how to do this?

Comment: What is your Update Contact Activity doing? That should be adding contacts to a Data Extension you've created, or you can mark subscribers in your Journey Data Extension and filter from there

Comment: Alternatively, if it is a matter of storing people in a DE to create an audience, you could always create a measure and reference the particular link you want to use. 

Using a DE, would require a boolean field in the DE e.g. "LinkA" which is updated to true, with the update contact activity. Depending on how many links, you can then create a filtered DE based on that field to segment out all of those who clicked linkA - but depends on your full requirement?

Comment: @KennethWagner need to create a DE with false boolean field and duplicate that for Update contact activity so when the user clicks the link the false will convert to true?

Comment: not exactly how it works. Essentially, you design a flow: Step 1 send email, step 2: wait, step 3: engagement split. What happens is that after a "Set" wait period it will evaluate and update the boolean. It will not happen live. If you need something live, the only way is to have the link direct to a landing page which executes some code, which after executing directs to final destination. If you just need to create a segment at any one time, the journey or a measure (or a query activity) would be the way forward.

Comment: @KennethWagner Could you kindly guide me on how to do this step-by-step? I'm just new here on Marketing Cloud.

Comment: What is the full requirement? :) is it live or is a manually generated segment enough? :)

Comment: I need automated. :)

Comment: @KennethWagner we need to create a journey. Once they clicked the specific link on the email they will receive an follow up email. Also, will send the lead clicks to a specific email address.

Comment: And you want this Real time correct? (Complexity / implementation time of Real time vs. other Solutions is a Factor of 5-10x)

Comment: @KennethWagner yep, real time. Is this possible?

Comment: will post an answer as i need formatting options :)